# Mongo database connection error using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting error while connecting to mongo db in local using nodejs . This was working fine few days back also Getting error like -

> Unsupported OP_QUERY command: find. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal

Package.json

```json
"dependencies": {
    "app-root-path": "^2.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bull": "^3.14.0",
    "casbin": "^3.0.4",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-http": "^4.0.0",
    "connect-redis": "^3.4.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "crud-sdk": "^1.0.12",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "cryptr": "^4.0.2",
    "document-reader": "1.0.8",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "esql_generator": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1",
    "express-jwt-blacklist": "^1.1.0",
    "express-rate-limit": "^3.3.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^6.11.1",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "helmet": "^3.13.0",
    "jaeger-client": "^3.17.2",
    "json-schema-faker": "^0.5.0-rc23",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "kafka-node": "^4.1.3",
    "login-sdk": "0.0.3",
    "mkdir": "0.0.2",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.13",
    "mongoskin": "^2.1.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.3.0",
    "opentracing": "^0.14.4",
    "pm2": "^4.2.1",
    "prom-client": "^13.1.0",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "simple-git": "^1.126.0",
    "spdy": "^3.4.7",
    "swagger-parser": "^8.0.4",
    "swagger-stats": "^0.95.11",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^3.0.10",
    "validate-fields": "^5.1.1",
    "winston": "^3.0.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^3.3.1",
    "yaml_generator_apiconnect": "^3.0.56",
    "zip-folder": "^1.0.0"
  },
```

Kindly help on the issue.

Comment: Can anyone have idea why this is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 6.0 removed the OP_QUERY opcode from the wire protocol.  If you driver is still sending that opcode, that probably means you are using a really old driver.  The newer OP_MSG opcode, introduced in MongoDB 3.6 should be used instead.

Check the [compatibility chart](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/compatibility/#compatibility), and upgrade to a driver that supports MongoDB version 6.0

Comment: I changed the driver to 3.6 and mongo db to 4.2 but still getting the issue

Comment: mongodb 4.2 supports op_query, did you restart the node after changing the binary?